# MYSQL Basic Select

Tags: mysql

Hello since I am new to mysql I have one question regarding selection. I am studying on https://www.w3schools.com/ and practicing on https://www.hackerrank.com/.

On hackerrank.com I have a question:

Query the list of CITY names starting with vowels (i.e., a, e, i, o, or u) from STATION. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

So someone more qualified explain why does code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY LIKE '[aeiouAEIOU]%';
```

works on [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com)

and does not work on hackerrank.com.

But this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[aeiouAEIOU]'
ORDER BY CITY;
```

do work.

Comment: *why does code .. works on www.w3schools.com and does not work on hackerrank.com* Because w3school uses **NOT** MySQL.

Comment: w3schools is a very low-quality resource and should be avoided whenever possible. It's the "WikiHow" of programming. The official MySQL documentation is far better, and there are additional resources in the form of proper courses. Just reading "tutorials" and trying hacker challenges is a really ineffective way of learning.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is worth answering, because your first query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE '[aeiouAEIOU]%';
```

in fact would be valid and would run on other databases, such as SQL Server.  But MySQL does not support the `[aeiouAEIOU]` enhanced `LIKE` syntax.  So you need to use `REGEXP` instead.  If you wanted to use `LIKE` only with MySQL, then you could use:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE UPPER(CITY) LIKE 'A%' OR
      UPPER(CITY) LIKE 'E%' OR
      UPPER(CITY) LIKE 'I%' OR
      UPPER(CITY) LIKE 'O%' OR
      UPPER(CITY) LIKE 'U%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo: It should be `CITY`,  not `CIRY`.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE '[aeiouAEIOU]%';
```

No idea why it works on [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) though.

If you only mistyped here on StackOverflow, then the problem is probably that pattern matching and regular expressions are handled differently by different database systems, so the interpretation of certain pattern matching syntax can differ.

Comment: please vote to close typo questions instead of answering them. you can comment pointing out the typo. also, from the edits to the question, it seems that that was just a copying error and not the actual cause of the problem.